# get the data attribute value of closest tr children

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, razor

Confusing title...
However I want to get the data-attr value of some td's which are in the same table as the button which triggers the event.

Here is the table, or rather the body of the table:

```
<tr class="reihe">
<td data-datum="@iiEntry.ccDatum">@iiEntry.ccEntryID</td>
<td class="size" data-firma="@iiEntry.ccBesucherFirma">@iiEntry.ccBesucherFirma</td>
<td class="size" data-name="@iiEntry.ccBesucherFirma">@iiEntry.ccBesucherName</td>
<td class="size" data-status="@iiEntry.ccStatus">@iiEntry.ccStatus</td>
<td class="size" data-ansprechpartner="@iiEntry.ccAnsprechpartner">@iiEntry.ccAnsprechpartner</td>
<td><button class="btn btn-default signin" id="signin-@iiEntry.ccEntryID">Anmelden</button></td>
<td><button class="btn btn-default delete">Löschen</button></td>
</tr>
```

And the script which should handle all that:

```
    $("[id^='signin']").click(function() {
        var lCompleteRow = $(this).closest("tr");
        var lFirma = $(lCompleteRow[0]).data("firma");

        alert(lCompleteRow);
     });
```

Now, I already tried a lot and with what I got now I can access the `tr` but I can't figure out a way to get the value of the data attribute of the `td` or I just get `undefined` returned.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Don't see any `data` attribute on `tr`. Are you adding it dynamically?

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant the data attributes of the `td`s

Comment: Which `td`? Give example

Comment: Basicly, I need the data of all of them but for this to be answered one would be enough. Lets say just `data-firma`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lCompleteRow` refers to the `tr` element. It doesn't have any data so the `data` method returns `undefined`. You should select the target cell before calling the `data` method.

```
lCompleteRow.children('[data-firma]').data('firma');
```

Another option is:

```
$(this.parentNode).siblings('[data-firma]').data('firma');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".signin").click(function() {
        var lCompleteRow = $(this).closest("tr").children("td:eq(1)").attr('data-firma');
        console.log(lCompleteRow);
 });
```